# compare-windows backwards in emacs to go back to previous diff

Tags: emacs, compare, window

I use compare-windows a lot but was hoping that there is backward functionality "to go back to the previous diff".
Is there such function?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code of `compare-windows`, it seems that it already pushes the mark. And the doc string says the same thing. Have you tried using `C-u C-SPC` or any of the other ways to navigate around the `mark-ring`?

```
,----
| compare-windows is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in
| `compare-w.el'.
| 
| It is bound to C-M-=, C-= w, menu-bar tools compare window.
| 
| (compare-windows IGNORE-WHITESPACE)
| 
| Compare text in current window with text in next window.
| Compares the text starting at point in each window,
| moving over text in each one as far as they match.
| 
| This command pushes the mark in each window
| at the prior location of point in that window.
| If both windows display the same buffer,
| the mark is pushed twice in that buffer:
| first in the other window, then in the selected window.
| 
| A prefix arg means reverse the value of variable
| `compare-ignore-whitespace'.  If `compare-ignore-whitespace' is
| nil, then a prefix arg means ignore changes in whitespace.  If
| `compare-ignore-whitespace' is non-nil, then a prefix arg means
| don't ignore changes in whitespace.  The variable
| `compare-windows-whitespace' controls how whitespace is skipped.
| If `compare-ignore-case' is non-nil, changes in case are also
| ignored.
| 
| If `compare-windows-sync' is non-nil, then successive calls of
| this command work in interlaced mode:
| on first call it advances points to the next difference,
| on second call it synchronizes points by skipping the difference,
| on third call it again advances points to the next difference and so on.
`----
```

Comment: While useful, it's not clear how this answer answers this question?

Comment: It is unclear what "other ways to navigate around the mark-ring" has to do with what the original questioner asked - how "to go back to the previous diff".  Imagine I've got two buffers visible and I'm at the end of both of them.  The end of both buffers are the same, but the start of each differ.  How do I search backwards to where (reading backwards) the buffers diverge?

Comment: @SomeoneElse: You're right. Navigating the mark ring in one buffer won't also move point to the corresponding diff in the other window. I'll leave the answer as written, but I agree that it doesn't answer the question. Thx.